# Dependency Injection in each other in Swift

Tags: swift

I am injecting the classes each other as follows, but when I run the app, app crashes. What is wrong with this implementation? It shows unsafeMutableAddressor.

```
class NetworkManager {
  
  static let shared = NetworkManager()
  let analyticsManager: ServiceManager

  init(serviceManager:ServiceManager = .shared) {
    self.serviceManager = serviceManager
  }
}

class ServiceManager {
  
  static let shared = ServiceManager()
  let networkManager: NetworkManager

  init(networkManager:NetworkManager = .shared) {
    self.networkManager = networkManager
  }
}
```

Comment: try `class NetworkManager {
    static let shared = NetworkManager()
    private init () { }
    lazy var serviceManager = ServiceManager.shared
}`

`class ServiceManager {
    static let shared = ServiceManager()
    private init () { }
    lazy var networkManager = NetworkManager.shared
}`

Comment: I would say you're creating some kind of loop. When you access `NetworkManager.shared` it will execute the `init` method with the default param `.shared`  which will execute the `init` method of the `ServiceManager`  which will trigger the `NetworkManager` initialiser once again ...

Comment: @LeoDabus, you approach has been tested and it works. Are there any drawbacks on using your approach compared to dependency injection?

Comment: Not that I know if you are using singleton approach on both of them